# How to Re Render an outputPanel on a button click?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, visualforce-component

So basically I'm making a visualforce page and there is a section that needs to be re rendered on a button click. From what I've read on the internet I can use outputpanel to achieve this. What I need to do is when I click on the button, that outputpanel should be replaced by another outputpanel.

**Here is a screenshot of the page so far:**

[image]

So there is a header and a sidebar that remains unchanged. The area inside the grey box is the what the outputpanel ought to contain. On clicking the save and continue button I need to replace this output panel with the next one in the form. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use reRender outputpanel.

```
<apex:outputPanel **id="refresh"**>
   // which part you want to rerender place inside between this opening and closing 
 outputPanel

</apex:outputPanel>


<apex:commandButton action="{!youractionname}" **reRender="refresh"** name="click" title="click"/>
```